# How to define a specific array of array type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, data-structures, typing

I am learning advanced types in TypeScript and I was wondering that is it somehow possible to define this kind of type somehow.

Idea is to have a class A that has a constructor that should accept an array of limited arrays or array of objects or any other suitable data type such that all the inner data structures would accept only two items such that the first one could be defined when calling the constructor and the other one would be fixed? If the type isn't defined it should accept all primitive types, but the second would still be fixed.

Something like this for example:

```js
interface Inner<T> {
  first: T,
  second: number
}
```

```js
class A<T> {
  constructor(arrayofxs: Array<Inner<T>>) { 
    // Do something
  }

}
```

Then using it something like this. when the type is not specificly set, the first argument would accept all primitives or object

```js
new A([['asd', 1], [123, 2], [{a: 1, b:123}, 3], ...])
```

and then when it's set it would only accept the set type as the first:

```js
new A<string>([['asd', 1], ['123', 2], ['qwerty', 3], ...])
```

The inner array don't have to be specificly array.

If I define the inner structure as

```js
type Inner = Array<T|number>
```

That wouldn't set the order of the arguments nor limit the amount of arguments. That's why I think the array isn't suitable as the inner structure, but I should probably use object.

If I define the inner type as following:

```js
type Inner<T> = [T, number]
```

That would kind of work, but then the instantiating without specifying the T will set the T as the type of the first array's element. And the same happens actually with the first type too. Type T seems to be set to the type of the first element.

```js
new A([['asd', 1], [123, 2], ... ])
```

The second inner array `[123, 2]` would show error

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

I could use it like this

```js
new A<any>([['asd', 1], [123, 2], ...])
```

But then using `any` is a really bad practice and I don't want to use it.

How could I possibly achieve this kind of typing?

Comment: Is the first element not `any`? It's only bad practice when you *can* use a more specific type.

Comment: To be honest, I am not exactly sure how ```any``` works. It is any in a sense that it should allow all types, but then it shouldn't accept types like ```never, null, undefined, void``` etc. I am also not sure, if variables with those types could be even assigned to an array in any case. But they could, I think ```any``` might allow that and that would be wrong.

Comment: In the docs it said that

**_"The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself). Even any isn’t assignable to never."_**

But that doesn't say if it's possible to assign ```never``` to ```any``` for example

Comment: Suddenly came back to this old question and @Artyer you were right. I seem to have had some insane misunderstanding and confusion back when I was thinking about this. Tuple type with `any` is definitely the correct solution here. No idea what did I needed this for though.